# How can a pandas dataframe with a TimedeltaIndex by grouped by nearest whole day?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a pandas DataFrame with an index of `pd.TimeDeltas` some of which are fractions of days. I'd like to use `df.groupby` to group the rows by whole days (ignoring the fractions of days) so that I can calculate the mean.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
idx = [pd.Timedelta('1.2 days'), pd.Timedelta('1.2 days'), pd.Timedelta('3.8 days'), pd.Timedelta('3.8 days'), pd.Timedelta('4.2 days'), pd.Timedelta('4.2 days')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.index = idx

df
Out: 
    a   b   c
1 days 04:48:00     1   2   3
1 days 04:48:00     2   3   4
3 days 19:12:00     3   4   5
3 days 19:12:00     1   2   3
4 days 04:48:00     2   3   4
4 days 04:48:00     3   4   5
```

The line below produces the desired a result however it creates extra rows for each day so there are rows full of NaNs which I subsequently remove with `df.dropna()`. Is there a better approach to doing this?

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).aggregate(np.mean).dropna()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine, or you can just group by `df.index.days` as below:

```
In [196]: df.groupby(df.index.days).mean()
Out[196]:
     a    b    c
1  1.5  2.5  3.5
3  2.0  3.0  4.0
4  2.5  3.5  4.5
```

The difference in the two methods is where things get grouped on the margins. In yours, something at `2 days, 02:00:00` would get grouped with the 1-day rows since `pd.Grouper` will start with the first example, whereas in mine, it will get a separate row since it treats midnight as the start of a new group.